# Counting the number of accounts and their songs for last 6 months

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the query where i am trying to get the last 6 months accounts and how much they contibuted by adding add for every month, like last 6 months can have 10 accounts and those 10 accounts have contributed to how many songs combined

my query is like tis

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Quantity
            FROM tblsong s
            INNER JOIN tblaccount AS a ON a.AccountID = s.AccountID 
            where a.CreatedDateTime BETWEEN '2020-12-13' 
            AND '2021-06-13'
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your explanation is also not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

for each accont you should use a group by  for AccountID

```
SELECT a.AccountID, COUNT(*) AS Quantity
FROM tblsong s
INNER JOIN tblaccount AS a ON a.AccountID = s.AccountID 
where a.CreatedDateTime BETWEEN '2020-12-13' 
AND '2021-06-13'
GROUP BY a.AccountID
```